# One XML, several XML outputs with xslt transformation

Tags: xml, file, xslt

I have straight forward XML formed:

```
<root> 
<product code="article_1">   some other code </product>
<product code="article_2">  some other code </product> ... and so on... 
</root>
```

I am trying to put every  node into separate xml which would then need to be named accordingly to code value in that product node. So for example first product node in above xml would be in xml named article_1.xml, second would be in xml named article_2.xml ... and so on.

Can this be done with xslt :D and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime can do that:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:result-document href="{@code}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Some XSLT 1.0 processors like xsltproc also have extension allowing a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I came up with similar code, but did not run it trough XSLT 2.0 processor :D thanks a lot, that was perfect 10 answer.